# Set authentication_string in Mysql 8.0.19

Tags: mysql, password

Trying to reset root's password, I end up at this line:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('1234') where user='root'
```

which leads to a mean syntax error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('1234') where user='root''
```

replacing `password('1234')` by `'1234'` works, so it looks like the 'password' function got missing. How do I hash my password then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ALTER_USER` instead of `SET authentication_string`:

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';

Answer (score 0):

didnt work same error.mysql> Alter user set authentication_string=password('Imag@123') whereuser='root';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set authentication_string=password('Imag@123') where user='root'' at line 1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177597)